# Find the commit current *master* refers to

Tags: git

If I would like to know which commit current *master* branch is referring to, how could I do that?

Is there a way to check the SHA1 of master in GIT?

Comment: sure, `git rev-parse some-branch` should give you the commit id that the branch is pointing to (to the best of your current knowledge.... if it's a remote branch it might have moved and you won't know about it until you fetch).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [`rev-parse`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) command for that:

```bash
git rev-parse master
```

This will return the SHA-1 of the commit being referenced by the `master` branch.